# Why is T-SQL TRY/CATCH so limited?

Tags: t-sql, try-catch

There are several types of error that T-SQL's TRY/CATCH won't catch at all (see below). Some of these are understandable (though I'd prefer for low-severity errors to also be caught, as they would be in application code), and some are unavoidable because errors that terminate the session don't even allow the CATCH to execute.

But why the limitation on compilation errors in the same scope? Is it impossible to handle or was it a deliberate decision? If the latter, what was the reasoning for it? Why can we catch compilation errors once they reach the parent scope, but not in the current scope?

Also, I wasn't around for the "good old days", but apparently it's possible to catch these using the old methods of error handling, so why not at least just handle it the same way under the hood?

> - Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or lower.
> - Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL Server Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error occurs that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection is not disrupted, TRY...CATCH will handle the error.
> - Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client connections.
> - When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the KILL statement.
>
> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.
> - Object name resolution errors

Comment: The "Why" question are not easy ones. Some of the decision are only known to the DB engine develeopers/product owner. I would recommend: http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: For syntax errors, the entire batch is first parsed before it's run; if there's a syntax error then the `TRY...CATCH` will never happen because the batch isn't run. It would be like expecting a `TRY...CATCH` in C# to catch a syntax error, however, because of said syntax error you can't build the project.